# How to add spacing between checkboxlist items?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, checkboxlist

I have checkboxlist within a table I am using. The checklist I need to line up with checkboxes in the second column. The spacing of each row of the textboxes(second row) is 26px. I can not find how to do spacing between items on checkbox list. Setting margins only does the outside of the list not items within.

[image]

[image]

I tried cellspacing but I cant get it quite lined up.

Update 2

```
<td style="vertical-align: top" rowspan="7"  Width="175" style="padding: 0;">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbtasklist" runat="server" CssClass="radiobutton">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Task 1">Task 1</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Task 2">Task 2</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Task 3">Task 3</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Task 4</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Task 5">Task 5</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Other1">Other</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Other2">Other</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>


                    </td>
                <td class="auto-style187" style="vertical-align: top" colspan="2">

                    &nbsp;</td>


.auto-style187 {
        height: 26px;
        width: 357px;
    }
```

Update 3:
  Would it be easier to do a checkbox for each line so I can use the same CSS as the other column?

The reason for the checkbox list is for validation that 1 must be selected.

Comment: Have you tried the CheckBoxList.CellSpacing property? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.cellspacing(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are looking for this

```
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="width: 100%">



    <table class="auto-style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3">
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" Height="163px">
                    <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>c</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>d</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>e</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>f</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style8">
                <table class="auto-style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>aaaa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style6">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style7">aaaa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>aaaa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style10">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style11">aaaa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style12">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style13">aaaa</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox6_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>aaaa</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style14"></td>
            <td class="auto-style15"></td>
            <td class="auto-style11"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style9">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    </div>

    </form>
```

see the image

[image: updated one]

I just took table inside a table .You can just remove the unwanted column as your desire

don't forget to edit the text box lineup its up to you

Comment: The text is slightly off to the text boxes which they want perfect lined up.

Comment: hey now look this updated one i hope this is appropiate

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try with this on your CSS:

```
checkbox { padding-bottom: 10px; }
```